# Dog Salad RNG Debunk

Tags: undertale

In [a certain Sans clip](https://youtu.be/Vr4IYjeplJA?t=210), an alternative consumable build is used in place of the optimal inventory (Pie, Noodles, Steak, 3x Snow, 2x Hero):

```
Name - HP

Steak - 60
I. Noodles - 90
(x4) L. Hero - 40
(x2) Dog Salad - (2 || 10 || 30 || 91)

Note: HP value reflects an individual item's yield, not accounting for the quantity in possession.
```

Now, if you're decent enough at the fight, you can certainly omit some unnecessary items.
The bizarre part lies in the Salads.
This is the only time I've seen someone rely on Dog Salad, so I started wondering whether or not they were legitimately useful.

**Does anyone have the *precise* probability for each occurrence?**